# Selenium Python: can't login to a website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access to a website with selenium python, but when i'm pressing the connect button a page appear telling me that i might be using a proxy or a vpn or my connection is suspicious, i think it's because i send a lot of requests from this website because i never had this problem before.

I use uc chromedriver

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
```

to bypass a cloudfare captcha at the beggining of the website

I tried from my personnal driver firefox to connect and the same message appear so i really think it's because i ask to much things to the website but i don't know how i can do now.

message from the website • We've detected suspicious activity on the network you're using. • You're accessing our service through a VPN, proxy, or "unblocker" service

Comment: message from the website
•
We've detected suspicious activity on the network you're using.
•
You're accessing our service through a VPN, proxy, or "unblocker" service

Comment: have you tried using your user account? Your most likely not handing it back the cookie it gives to you, so its confused.